# How to define a python lambda getting the first element?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, group-by

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 0, 1, 1], 
                   'B': [1, 3, 8, 10], 
                   'C': ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta']})
```

Now, I would like to group the data using own lambdas, but they behave different from what I expect. The lambda in the following example should return the first value of the column in the group:

```
df.groupby('A', as_index = False).agg({'B':'mean', 
                                       'C': lambda x: x[0]})
```

The code throws the `KeyError: 0`, which is unclear to me since `['alpha', 'bravo'][0]` gives `'alpha'`

So overall the desired output:

```
    A   B          C
0   0   2    'alpha'
1   1   9  'charlie'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need select first value in group is necessary use [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html) or [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html) for select by position:

```
df1 = df.groupby('A', as_index = False).agg({'B':'mean', 'C': lambda x: x.iat[0]})
```

Another solution is use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('A', as_index = False).agg({'B':'mean', 'C': 'first'})
print (df1)
   A  B        C
0  0  2    alpha
1  1  9  charlie
```

> Can you add an explanation of why the lambda doesn't work?

Problem is for second group, there is index not `0`, but `2`, what raise error, because `x[0]` try seelct by index with `0` and for second group it not exist:

```
df1 = df.groupby('A', as_index = False).agg({'B':'mean', 'C': lambda x: print (x[0])})
print (df1)
alpha <- return first value of first group only, because alpha has index 0
alpha
alpha
```

So if set index `0` for first values of groups it working with this sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 0, 1, 1], 
                   'B': [1, 3, 8, 10], 
                   'C': ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta']}, index=[0,1,0,1])
print (df)
   A   B        C
0  0   1    alpha <- index is 0
1  0   3    bravo
0  1   8  charlie <- index is 0
1  1  10    delta

df1 = df.groupby('A', as_index = False).agg({'B':'mean', 'C': lambda x: x[0]})
print (df1)
   A  B        C
0  0  2    alpha
1  1  9  charlie
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation of why the lambda doesn't work?

Comment: @Barmar - Explanation for you.

Answer (score 1):

Small **explanation** on why your `lambda` function won't work.

When we use `groupby` we get an groupby object back:

```
g = df.groupby('A')

print(g)
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x0000023AA1BB41D0>
```

---

When we access the elements in our groupby object, we get *grouped dataframes* back:

```
for idx, d in g:
    print(d, '\n')

   A  B      C
0  0  1  alpha
1  0  3  bravo 

   A   B        C
2  1   8  charlie
3  1  10    delta
```

So thats why we need to threat these elements as DataFrames. As jezrael already pointed out in his answer, there are several ways to access the first value in your `C` column:

```
for idx, d in g:
    print(d['C'].iat[0])
    print(d['C'].iloc[0], '\n')

alpha
alpha 

charlie
charlie
```